# frames overlap in python3 matplotlib animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I'm getting confused with the FuncAnimation method. I was trying to show real-time sensor data on my raspberry pi using GPIOs. I set the x range to 100. When my data frames are over 100, I will only pick the recent 100 frames to show. At the beginning when the number of frames is less than 100, the pic shows correctly. The problem is that when frames are over 100, the later pic will overlap with the former pic and the graph just mess up. Here's the beginning graph and the overlap graph.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfn2U.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM0TC.png)

I checked the matplotlib API and I changed the param "blit" from True to False.
The overlap disappears but the frame rate is becoming too low.
Since I also used FuncAnimation with blit set True in another code and the overlap didn't appear, I guess there something else wrong.

The overlap code is below:

```
max_limit = 20
fig, ax = plt.subplots(light_num, 1)
data = []
lines = []
for i in range(light_num):
    data.append([])
    ln_one_light, = ax[i].plot([], [], 'r-')
    lines.append(ln_one_light)

def init():
    for i in range(light_num):
        ax[i].set_xlim(0, max_limit)
        ax[i].set_ylim(lower_bound, upper_bound)
    return lines

def update(frame):
    # print(frame)
    global data
    for i in range(light_num):
        data[i].append(frame[i])
        if len(data[i]) > max_limit:
            data[i] = data[i][1:]
    time_axis = np.arange(len(data[i]))
    for i in range(light_num):
        # print(time_axis, data[i])
        lines[i].set_data(time_axis, data[i])
    return lines

def gen_function():
    res_array = []
    output_string = ''
    for i in range(light_num):
        val = GPIO.input(light_io_array[i])
        res_array.append(val)
        output_string = output_string + str(val) + ' '
    # print(res_array)
    lights_data_writer.update_data(output_string)
    yield res_array

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=gen_function, interval = 500, repeat = True,
                    init_func=init, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

The code that I used with blit set as True, but no overlap happens:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1)
data_x, data_y, data_z = [], [], []
ln_x, = ax[0].plot([], [], 'r-')
ln_y, = ax[1].plot([], [], 'r-')
ln_z, = ax[2].plot([], [], 'r-')

def init():
    for i in range(3):
        ax[i].set_xlim(0, 100)
        ax[i].set_ylim(-5, 5)
    return (ln_x, ln_y, ln_z)

def update(frame):
    (x, y, z) = frame
    global data_x, data_y, data_z
    data_x.append(x)
    data_y.append(y)
    data_z.append(z)
    if len(data_x) > 100:
        data_x = data_x[1:]
        data_y = data_y[1:]
        data_z = data_z[1:]
    time_xyz = np.arange(len(data_x))
    # print(time_xyz, data_x)
    ln_x.set_data(time_xyz, data_x)
    ln_y.set_data(time_xyz, data_y)
    ln_z.set_data(time_xyz, data_z)
    return (ln_x, ln_y, ln_z)

def gen_function():
    while True:
        (x, y, z) = adxl345.getAxes()
        output_string = 'acc '+str(x)+' '+str(y)+' '+str(z)
        imu_data_writer.update_data(output_string)
        yield (x, y, z)

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=gen_function, interval = 100,
                    init_func=init, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Thank you for anyone who can have a look and check out what I have done wrong.